# get all the subscriptions properties for a component angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a this following method that should unsubscribes all the subscriptions for a component on ngDestroy event.

```
 public clear(obj: any): void {
    for (let p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && obj[p] instanceof Subscription) {
            (obj[p] as Subscription).unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

the condition: **obj[p] instanceof Subscription** always fails, the error message is: "Subscription is not define"

is there any way to detect that the property is a Subscription?

Thank you

Comment: Did you import `Subscription` from the `rxjs` package? Alternatively did you tried to just declare an array like this: `private subscriptions: Subscription[] = []` and push your subscriptions in and on `ngDestroy` hook just do the following `this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());`

Comment: Yes I did import the Subscription from rxjs, I tried to work with array but I want one method in a util class that each component will call on destroy

Comment: I tried the same thing, in my setup it's working properly, so there must be something wrong with your import of `Subscription`. Little side-note: You dont have to cast obj[p] to `Subscription` Typescript already knows it must be of type `Subscription` because of the `instanceof`

Comment: @user3132295 is `obj` in your `clear` function of type `Array<Subscription>`??

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem the import is case sensitive so I just changed the

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/subscription";
```

to

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
```

and now it works :)